# discord.js slash commands - "This interaction failed" on long running functions

Tags: node.js, express, discord, discord.js, bots

in node.js, how do you defer a slash command's response?

in discord, the result is:

> micker
> BOT
> — Today at 5:23 PM
> This interaction failed
> Only you can see this • Dismiss message

here is the code for the bot:

```
import 'dotenv/config';
import express from 'express';
import {
  InteractionType,
  InteractionResponseType,
  InteractionResponseFlags,
  MessageComponentTypes,
  ButtonStyleTypes,
} from 'discord-interactions';
import { VerifyDiscordRequest, getRandomEmoji, DiscordRequest } from './utils.js';
import * as generate from './generate.cjs';
import { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } from 'discord.js';



// Create an express app
const app = express();
// Get port, or default to 3000
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
// Parse request body and verifies incoming requests using discord-interactions package
app.use(express.json({ verify: VerifyDiscordRequest(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY) }));

// Store for in-progress games. In production, you'd want to use a DB
const activeGames = {};

/**
 * Interactions endpoint URL where Discord will send HTTP requests
 */
app.post('/interactions', async function (req, res) {
  // Interaction type and data
  const { type, id, data } = req.body;

  /**
   * Handle verification requests
   */
  if (type === InteractionType.PING) {
    return res.send({ type: InteractionResponseType.PONG });
  }

  /**
   * Handle slash command requests
   * See https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands#slash-commands
   */
  if (type === InteractionType.APPLICATION_COMMAND) {
    const { name } = data;

    // "test" command
    if (name === 'test') {
      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      return res.send({
        type: InteractionResponseType.CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE,
        data: {
          // Fetches a random emoji to send from a helper function
          content: 'hello world ' + getRandomEmoji(),
        },
      });
    }

    // "test" command
    if (name === 'talk') {


      var deferMessage=JSON.stringify({
                type: InteractionResponseType.DEFERRED_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE
            });

      await res.write(deferMessage);


      var generated = await generate.generateTweet();

      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      var talkMessage = JSON.stringify({
                type: "+InteractionResponseType.DEFERRED_UPDATE_MESSAGE+",
                        data: {
                                    content: getRandomEmoji() + generated,
                              },
                });

      res.write(talkMessage);
      return res.end();

    }

  }
});


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port', PORT);
});
```

also tried using send() instead of write()

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/receiving-and-responding

https://discordjs.guide/slash-commands/response-methods.html#deferred-responses

here is some more text

Answer (score -1):

When deferring using HTTP interactions, the HTTP response sends the defer and then resolves the defer via the REST API. Here is an example
(Also, I think you should refrain from using `var`)

```js
if (name === 'talk') {

      const deferMessage=JSON.stringify({
                type: InteractionResponseType.DEFERRED_CHANNEL_MESSAGE_WITH_SOURCE
            });

      await res.write(deferMessage);


      const generated = await generate.generateTweet();

      // Send a message into the channel where command was triggered from
      const talkMessage = JSON.stringify({
             content: getRandomEmoji() + generated,
      });
      await fetch(`https://discord.com/api/v10/webhooks/${id}/${req.body.token}/messages/@original`, { body: talkMessage, headers: { Authorization: `Bot <INSERT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE>` }, method: "PATCH" });

      return res.end();
```

Comment: I get :
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576

    Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);

          ^



TypeError: Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.

    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)

    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

    at async file:///home/nonki/neo/discord-example-app/app.js:117:31



Node.js v20.3.1

Comment: and with method: "PATCH", I get:
{"message": "Unknown Webhook", "code": 10015}

It should work:
https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#edit-webhook-message

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add method. Fixed